# Nativescript bind a response to observable

Tags: android, response, httpresponse, observable, nativescript

I am new to Nativescript and trying to build an Android App.I am sending a POST request and getting an proper response.But the problem is I can not bind the response data to Observable.I am trying to bind the **`data[0].value`** to **`price`**  in my Viewmodel.But I have failed to do that.But if I try to set hardcoded data like this **`Viewmodel.set("price","1000$")`** then it's ok.But i can not set response data.

```
var fetchModule = require("fetch");

 var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

 var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

 var data;

 var person;

 var priceFromResponse;


     function ModelViewModel() {

      var viewmodel = new Observable();

      var Viewmodel =new Observable();

           viewmodel.get=function(model){

           data = model;

           }

     var viewModel = new ObservableArray();

            viewModel.load = function() {


            fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/get_model", {

            method: "POST",

            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

            body: JSON.stringify({
                     brand: data,
            })  
            }).then(r => { return r.json(); }).then(function (data) {  

           for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                viewModel.push({
                model: data[i].product,

                 });  

             };  

             priceFromResponse =data[0].value;


            }).then(function(price){ 

            })

            }

            viewModel.empty = function() {
            while (viewModel.length) {
            viewModel.pop();
            } 
            };

            **Viewmodel.set("price",priceFromResponse);**

           return [viewModel,viewmodel,Viewmodel];

}

module.exports = ModelViewModel;
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you want var viewModel = new ObservableArray([]);.  Notice the empty array brackets.  I think without it, you're trying to push your object to an uninitialized array.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: Also, I see you have three variables named view model with different cases.  You might want to use different names.  Not sure how strict JavaScript is on case sensitivity.

Comment: Mr.Nic Raboy viewModel is working fine.My problem is with Viewmodel.Notice the case sensitivity.It's working fine with hardcoded data like Viewmodel.set("price","2000").But I want to set a response.like Viewmodel.set("price",priceFromResponse) where priceFromResponse=data[0].value.